# Azure DevOps - How do I create a Personal Access Token (PAT) so that it will show up for another user?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, access-token, servicenow

I created a PAT for customer's ServiceNow account (external user) to Integrate with our DevOps environment that we have stood up for their projects.  Everything connects fine, however now all comments/updates that are made are under my name.  Is there a way to change this?  Or in other words, can I create a PAT and then customize the user account associated with it?

Comment: Welcome at SO. Do you want to change with the PAT the account from the owner of the PAT. Or do you want to change an other user?

Answer (score 0):

No. Think of a PAT as portable credentials for an account. You can't change the user, because the PAT is **for** that user.

Typically for this kind of scenario, a service account is used.

Answer (score 0):

No, according to authentification guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops

> Use your PAT in place of your password.

Additionally, there no tools to manage the PATs of other project users because of security reasons. In this scenario, you may generate the PAT and use it to change information under another user.... that`s not the right story ))

In this case, you need to create a technical user and generate PAT associated with it. Additionally, you have to remember its password to renew the PAT periodically [Is there a way to renew a PAT via REST API?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#q-is-there-a-way-to-renew-a-pat-via-rest-api):

> No, we don't have a REST API to renew a PAT. You can only regenerate a
> PAT within the user interface (UI).